# Proper way to use @Published variable to get the update SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, data-binding

I have a view where I am running a "foreach" loop to draw some shapes.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RccFrameView: View {
@EnvironmentObject var frameViewModel: RccFrameViewModel

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(frameViewModel.frameRectInfoList) { frameRectInfo in
            // Drawing shapes based on "frameRectInfo"
        }
    }
    .onReceive(self.frameViewModel.$frameData) { _ in
        frameViewModel.extractFrameData(frameDataArray: frameViewModel.frameData, deviceModel: deviceModel)

    }
}
```

}

In the view model, I am assigning the "frameRectInfoList" value like this:

```
class RccFrameViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var frameData: NSArray = []
    @Published var shapeFillColour = Color.white
    @Published var shapeStrokeColour = Color.white
    @Published var frameRectInfoList: [RccFrameRectInfo] = []
    @Published var currentFrameType: LjFocusFrameType = .unknown
    
    func extractFrameData(frameDataArray: NSArray, deviceModel: RccDeviceModelWrapper) {
        if frameDataArray.count > 0 {
            for frameDict in frameDataArray {
                if let frameType = (frameDict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "frameType") as? Int,
                   let frameRects = (frameDict as AnyObject).object(forKey: "frameRects") as? [RccFrameRectInfo] {
                    currentFrameType = LjFocusFrameType(rawValue: frameType) ?? .unknown
                    
                    switch frameType {
                    case LjFocusFrameType.contrast.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = Color("FocusFrameGreen")
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                        
                    case LjFocusFrameType.contrastFlexibleMain.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = .white
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                        
                    case LjFocusFrameType.unknown.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = .white
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                    default: break
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But in this implementation, the `ForEach` loop in my view is calling after the full iteration of the for loop of "extractFrameData" function of the view model.

This called:

```
ForEach(frameViewModel.frameRectInfoList) { frameRectInfo in
            // Drawing shapes based on "frameRectInfo"
        }
```

After a full iteration of this:

```
for frameDict in frameDataArray {
                if let frameType = (frameDict as AnyObject).value(forKey: "frameType") as? Int,
                   let frameRects = (frameDict as AnyObject).object(forKey: "frameRects") as? [RccFrameRectInfo] {
                    currentFrameType = LjFocusFrameType(rawValue: frameType) ?? .unknown
                    
                    switch frameType {
                    case LjFocusFrameType.contrast.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = Color("FocusFrameGreen")
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                        
                    case LjFocusFrameType.contrastFlexibleMain.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = .white
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                        
                    case LjFocusFrameType.unknown.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = .white
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
                    default: break
                    }
                }
            }
```

But I want to run the `foreach` of my view:

```
ForEach(frameViewModel.frameRectInfoList) { frameRectInfo in
            // Drawing shapes based on "frameRectInfo"
        }
```

Whenever the `self.frameRectInfoList` get's some value in each case:

```
case LjFocusFrameType.contrast.rawValue:
                        if frameRects.count > 0 {
                            shapeFillColour = Color("FocusFrameGreen")
                            shapeStrokeColour = .black
                            self.frameRectInfoList = frameRects
                        }
```

I am mentioning 1 case as an example, but it will be like this for all `case` inside of the view model "extractFrameData" function.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `onChange` instead of `onReceive` in your view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RccFrameView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var frameViewModel: RccFrameViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(frameViewModel.frameRectInfoList) { frameRectInfo in
              // do stuff
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: frameViewModel.frameRectInfoList) { _ in
            // more stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But this is not working. Btw, the `@Published var frameData: NSArray = []` on the view model is getting value continuously from a call.